# Autofilter last 13 months in PIVOT TABLE

Tags: vba, pivot, autofilter

I have two slicers "Month" and "Year", I need a VBA code to auto-filter the PT on selection in Slicer for example, user select Month - march and Year 2017, Filter should be applied Month - April to March and Year - 2016 & 2017.

```
Sub Period_Last_12_Months()

Dim pi As PivotItem, Cutoffmonth As String, CuttoffYear As String
Dim sMonthName As String
Dim Calc As String

sMonthName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("margin pool").Range("B1").Value
Cutoffmonth = Format(DateAdd("m", -13, CDate(sMonthName & "/1/2000")), "mmmm")
cutoffyear = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("margin pool").Range("B2").Value
''  Calc = Cutoffmonth & " " & cutoffyear
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("margin pool").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    .ManualUpdate = True
    With .PivotFields("Month")
        For Each pi In .PivotItems
            pi.Visible = (Format(CDate(pi & "/1/2000"), "mmmm")) > Cutoffmonth
        Next pi
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Year")
        For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pi.Visible = DateValue(pi.Year) > cutoffyear
        Next pi
        End With
    .ManualUpdate = False

        End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The problem is i am automating the entire manual task and thus cannot ask user to add another column, put formula to convert the month and year value in raw data and then refresh the pivot.

Comment: Do you know the data structure ? what columns are `Month` and `Year` in ? Do you know the first empty column ? If yes, we can do it by code, and then refresh the `PivotTable` with the new Extra Column, sounds like a good start ?

Comment: Sounds Great! Month and Year are in column N and O. First empty column is AR

Comment: No, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Input")

Answer (score 0):

The code below will add a `Date` format in Column "AR" of the entire data in "Data Input" worksheet.

Afterwards it creates/update "PivotTable2" in "margin pool" worksheet.

At last, it will show only record within 390d (~13 months) of the selected date in cell "B2".

**Full Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Period_Last_12_Months()

Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache    As PivotCache
Dim PvtItm      As PivotItem
Dim PvtDataRng  As Range

Dim Cutoffmonth As String, CuttoffYear As String
Dim sMonthName As String
Dim Calc As String

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

' === first sort the data for the Pivot Table ===
With Worksheets("Data Input")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "O"

    .Range("AR2:AR" & LastRow).Formula = "=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(" & Chr(34) & "1/" & Chr(34) & ",N2," & Chr(34) & "/" & Chr(34) & ",O2))"
    .Range("AR2:AR" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

    Set PvtDataRng = .Range("A1:AR" & LastRow) ' <-- set the Range for the Pivot Table
End With

' === set the Pivot Table ===
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, PvtDataRng)

' Set the Pivot Table (already created in previous macro run)
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("margin pool").PivotTables("PivotTable2")

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' <-- pivot table still doesn't exist >> need to create it

    ' create a new Pivot Table in ws2 sheet, start from Cell A5
    Set PvtTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("margin pool").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("margin pool").Range("A5"), TableName:="PivotTable2")

    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("MyDate") ' add MyDate as Pivot Table's filter
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot table, with updated Pivot Cache
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If


Dim toDate As Date

toDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("margin pool").Range("B2").Value ' <-- get the date value from Cell B2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With PvtTbl
    .ManualUpdate = True
    With .PivotFields("MyDate") ' <-- depends on the column's header of the new column we added (I have in "AR1" Mydate as Text)
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each PvtItm In .PivotItems
            PvtItm.Visible = DateDiff("d", CDate(PvtItm.Name), toDate) < 13 * 30 ' <-- less than 13 months (took 30 days in a month)
        Next PvtItm
    End With
    .ManualUpdate = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Pivot Table Fields screen-shot:

[image]

Pivot Table result after running this code screen-shot:

- Value in cell "B2 is 01-01-2017 (Date Format)
- All Items within 390 days of that days are Visible

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138400/discussion-on-answer-by-shai-rado-autofilter-last-13-months-in-pivot-table).